# Ramda (or other FP lib) usage for selecting maybe null keys

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Let's say I have a data structure like:

```
let slots = {
  7 : [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
  8 : [ 'd', 'e', 'f' ]
}
let names = {
  a : { name : 'Joe' },
  b : { name : 'Doe' },
  c : { name : 'Cecilia' },
  d : { name : 'Hugh' }
}
```

... where `slots[x][y]` is correlated to `names`' keys.

Given that x and y are inputs that can rannge from 0 to 10, one would write, in order to get the names and account for the error cases:

```
let nameKey = (slots[x] || [])[y] //string or undefined
let name = (names[nameKey] || {}).name || ''
```

So here I've used things like `|| []` or `|| {}` in order to avoid probable errors with some inputs and null keys. I've heard that by using FP kits I can also achieve that in a cleaner way. What functions of Ramda (or any other FP kit) should I use in order to achieve that?

Comment: First, what is FP kit? Does FP stands for *Functional Programming*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ramda has [`pathOr`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pathOr):

```
let slots = {
  7 : [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
  8 : [ 'd', 'e', 'f' ]
}
let names = {
  a : { name : 'Joe' },
  b : { name : 'Doe' },
  c : { name : 'Cecilia' },
  d : { name : 'Hugh' }
}
```

You'd do:

```
let nameKey = R.pathOr(undefined, [x, y], slots);
//it'd be probably better to normalize it to always a string instead of undefined (but that's what you wrote)
let name = R.pathOr('', [nameKey, 'name'], names);
```